# LogCat "... n more"

Tags: android, logcat

Logcat is listing to some errors and the line ends with "... 4 more". How can i get all error messages?

```
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958): Process: com.example.gsubdata, PID: 4958
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.JdkHttpUrlConnectionSource.openConnection(JdkHttpUrlConnectionSource.java:33)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.getRequestConnection(HttpGDataRequest.java:386)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.<init>(HttpGDataRequest.java:281)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.<init>(GoogleGDataRequest.java:457)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest$Factory.createRequest(GoogleGDataRequest.java:94)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest$Factory.getRequest(HttpGDataRequest.java:165)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.createRequest(Service.java:760)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.createRequest(GoogleService.java:539)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.createFeedRequest(Service.java:1156)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:997)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.example.gsubdata.MySpreadsheetIntegration.doInBackground(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:97)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at com.example.gsubdata.MySpreadsheetIntegration.doInBackground(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:1)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-26 23:33:14.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4958):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: i don't know if i need more but when all error messages start with "at" there must be something else in the 4 lines?

Comment: Why do you need this? The relevant part will almost certainly by many lines above what you've posted and will include exceptions and "Caused by" logs which indicate which part of your code is causing the problem/

Comment: As a programmer, i learned to be skeptical about every bit.

Comment: Learn to read LogCat - line 97 of MySpreadsheetIntegration.java is throwing a `NullPointerException`. By the look of it, it's in the `doInBackground(...)` method of an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I know that but i would expect to stop the error messages aufter "Caused", so there are more lines with "at" and then it stops...i would like to know if you can open it or not... i don't get the logic about this hint.

Comment: No, sorry. As squonk said, the error is outlined. Do you need to know what line of the zygote main() the error threw? Read the logcat.

Comment: The "... n more" line is for the sake of brevity. I've often seen "... 11 more" or "... 15 more" but the root of the problem is whatever line in your own code that's causing the exception. If it showed every line all you'd be able to do is drill down into the AOSP source and work backwards up the stack trace at which point you'd arrive back at the line in your code which is causing the error. Unless you're a Google Android dev, why bother? It's your code which is throwing the exception, identify the line, fix the problem and stop worrying about it.

Comment: @Squonk you are completely right, thanks!